# Bus Route Program,What kind of algorithm and data-structure do I use?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

I have a question about Java algorithm of one program. I want to write an android program that provides information about "bus route". Program is worked that user selects one bus station(A station) and program says to user "take the bus number 4,and take off B station.And take the bus number 8 then take off C station." Anyone has an idea about that programs algorithm? What can I use for saving each bus route? `Queue`, `stack` or someting like that?  Can I use `BFS` or `DFS` algorithm for shortest bus route path?

`Purpose of program;` How can user finds the transportation route with using Bus. (Bus number 4 does not go to the station 8 directly,user needs transfer to station B)

`I need to know ;` Which data structure and which shortest path algorithm do I use.

[image: Thats a question's image that explaining above]

Comment: Why not use Dijkstra's Algorithm

Comment: @TejasPatel I searched you on google for asking this question but I do not find your email address... Now I am searching Dijkstra's Algorithm. Also I do not know which data structure shall I use.

Comment: @TeachMeJava You asked on Stack Overflow, you are not supposed to privately message users. That would prevent future users with the same problem from seeing the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Implementation for Dijkstra's Algorithm in Java](http://www.algolist.com/code/java/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

The place in code where the vertex are initialized, you initialize all your bus routes.

In place where adjacency matrix is defined, for each of your stop initialize with stops where buses are available. Now run the algorithm. You might keep additional info along each edge such as possible bus numbers.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that the outgoing edges from a node depend on the distance of the node from the start. Turns out Dijkstra still works, but the implementation works a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working Java in the background and you'd go for Dijkstra algorithm, you *basically* need to get and manage a graph instance. Maybe there are even graph libraries/implementations which would already got DFS and BFS algorithms and so Dijkstra or Kruskal.

I'd suggest creating a graph implementation based on a Java `HashTable`. Having each node as `Key` and the adjacency list as `Value` per each.

Using `ArrayList`'s, `Stack`'s `Queue` or `PriorityQueue` might help.

You'd maybe have to implement a simple `Node` class and get static methods for doing Dijsktra, DFS, Kruskal, BFS, etc.